# Как можно решить эту ошибку "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST" Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь сделать что то вроде todo листа, когда пробую сделать удаление, выходит эта ошибка "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST"
Пожалуйста подскажите в чем может быть ошибка, или что проверить и куда копать

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Pupil Page')


@section('content')

@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success ">
    {{ session()->get('success') }}
</div>
@endif

<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
    <a href ="{{ route('pupils.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Добавить ученика</a>
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table mt-3 ">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
                <th scope="col">Имя</th>
                <th scope="col">Отчество</th>
                <th scope="col">Дата Рождения</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($pupils as $pupil)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$pupil->surname}}</td>
                <td>{{$pupil->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$pupil->lastname}}</td>
                <td>{{$pupil->birthday}}</td>
                <td class = "table-buttons">

                    <a href = "{{route('pupils.edit', $pupil)}}" class="btn btn-primary">
                      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                    <form method = "POST" action = "{{ route('pupils.destroy', $pupil) }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit">delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('pupils', 'PupilsController');
```

PupilsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Pupils;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PupilsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pupils = Pupils::all();
        return view('pupils.index', compact('pupils'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pupils.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'surname' => 'required|max:255',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'birthday' => 'required|max:255',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        $pupils = new Pupils(
            [
                'surname' => $request->get('surname'),
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'lastname' => $request->get('lastname'),
                'birthday' => $request->get('birthday'),
                'address' => $request->get('address'),
            ]
        );

        $pupils->save();
        return redirect('/pupils')->with('success', 'Ученик добавлен!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Pupils  $pupils
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Pupils $pupils)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Pupils  $pupils
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Pupils $pupils)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Pupils  $pupils
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Pupils $pupils)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Pupils  $pupils
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Pupils $pupils)
    {

        $pupils->delete();

        return redirect('/pupils')->with('success', 'Ученик удален!');
    }
}
```

[image: так же прилагаю route list]

Comment: Гуглить пробовали ? 1) `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293326/the-delete-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head`, 2) `https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-delete-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-post` и т.д. (много в поиске)

Comment: @sousage1212  пробовал делать, то что там указано но не помогает, поэтому и написал сюда.

Comment: Вы вызываете путь, который не поддерживает DELETE, посмотрите на ваш скрин и скажите, какой путь вы вызываете.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov  вы имеете ввиду сделать так ? 
Route::delete('pupils', 'PupilsController@destroy')->name('pupils.destroy');

Comment: Вы передаете объект шаблонизатору, который не знает как его использовать чтобы сгенерировать путь. Вам нужно поменять route('pupils.destroy', $pupil) на route('pupils.destroy', $pupil->id) чтобы получать ID объекта, который затем через внутренние механизмы будет превращен в объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в web.php

`Route::get('pupils/{pupil}', [App\Http\Controllers\PupilsController ::class, 'destroy'])->name('pupils.destroy');`

В контролере метод

```
    public function destroy($pupils)
{
    Client::destroy($pupils);

    return back()->with('success', 'Ученик успешно удален!');
}
```

В view добавь

```
<a href = "{{route('pupils.destroy', $pupil)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
```